# How can i custom index blob data for search / sort?

Tags: sqlite

i can *display* blob data in a custom way, easily enough, but i want said data to be indexed / searchable / sortable according to how i would display it.

eg: if a binary blob has "file alias data" (which is basically a file path but with extra info such that the file can be found if moved), then in the display i want to show the "resolved" path, i also want to be able to sort by that and search by it.

how can i accomplish this? deterministic user-function? virtual table? relational link?

any ideas? i'm open to suggestions!

-dave

Comment: here is the actual data in the "blob" (yes, it's xml plist text):<br>
~~~
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>file status</key>
 <integer>2</integer>
 <key>path</key>
 <string>/Users/davec/Music/kJams/kJams Music/2 AM Club/PY23069/PY23069-00-2 AM Club-Not Your Boyfriend.xml</string>
 <key>type</key>
 <integer>4</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
~~~<br>
and the string i want to extract has the tag <string>

Comment: so i want to have this separate column be invisible to the user, and when i sort on the actual column, i want the table sorted by the virtual one.  is that crazy? or easy? also when the data is updated, i want the virtual data to auto update, can i do that with a "Trigger" ?

Answer (score 0):

Let;s say your BLOB data was based upon:-

```
blah blah blah
file alias data = c:/user/data/mydata.txt
file alias data = c:/user/data/otherdata.txt
file alias data = c:/user/data/moredata.txt
```

- blah blah blah just to ensure that
- interpreted that *"if a binary blob has "file alias data""* means it does rather than may do i.e. the expectation is that it does and that ***a*** means a single.

The Index for the above could be created using :-

```
CREATE INDEX resolved_main ON main (replace(thedata,hex('file alias data = '),''));
```

Then the following could be used to find `mydata` in the resolved path (1 row) returning the resolved path and order by the resolved :-

```
WITH 
    /* CTE */
    argcte(replarg,findinresolved) AS (
        SELECT 
            hex('file alias data = '), /* used to find and resolved */
            hex('mydata') /* data to search for */
        )
SELECT id,replace(thedata,(SELECT replarg FROM argcte),'') AS resolved,thedata
FROM main
WHERE
    instr(thedata,(SELECT replarg FROM argcte)) /* only consider resolvable rows */
    AND instr(resolved,(SELECT findinresolved FROM argcte)) /* primary search */
ORDER BY resolved /* sort */
;
```

- Obviously `'file alias data = '` and `'mydata'` would be amended accordingly to suit.

The following is the full SQL used to test the above :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  main;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, thedata BLOB);

INSERT INTO main VALUES
    (null,hex('blah blah blah')),
    (null,hex('file alias data = c:/user/data/mydata.txt')),
    (null,hex('file alias data = c:/user/data/otherdata.txt')),
    (null,hex('file alias data = c:/user/data/moredata.txt')),
    (null,hex('file alias data = c:/user/data/file alias data')) /* unlikely to be? */
;

WITH 
    /* CTE */
    argcte(replarg,findinresolved) AS (
        SELECT 
            hex('file alias data = '), /* used to find and resolved */
            hex('mydata') /* data to search for */
        )
SELECT id,replace(thedata,(SELECT replarg FROM argcte),'') AS resolved,thedata
FROM main
WHERE
    instr(thedata,(SELECT replarg FROM argcte)) /* only consider resolvable rows */
    AND instr(resolved,(SELECT findinresolved FROM argcte)) /* primary search */
ORDER BY resolved /* sort */
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  main;
```

When run the result is :-

i.e. only the 2nd row which is path file alias data = c:/user/data/**mydata**.txt

[image]

With the AND ..... clause commented out (i.e. get all resolved in sort order) then :-

[image]

- As can be seen sorted accordingly